# How to get the upload path

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm uploading an image to my apps directory and saving the upload path to database

I tried using `$this->upload->data()['full_path']`to get the output but it shows 
`C:\/xampp\/htdocs\/sample_app\/uploads\/users\/c93ccd78b2076528346216b3b2f701e6\/profile_image\/ccccfadb7af6f4cbd11855f6291dae26.jpg`

instead of

`C:/xampp/htdocs/sample_app/uploads/users/c93ccd78b2076528346216b3b2f701e6/profile_image/ccccfadb7af6f4cbd11855f6291dae26.jpg`..

shoud I just make a function the removes the `/`, or there's a better and appropriate way on doing this

here's the code that I'm using for testing

```
  public function getImage(){
    $directoryName = md5($this->input->post('username'));
    $directoryPath = './uploads/users/'.$directoryName.'/profile_image';

    if(!file_exists($directoryPath)){
        mkdir($directoryPath,  0777, TRUE);

        if(isset($_FILES["image"]["name"]))
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $directoryPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {   
                $data = $this->upload->display_errors();
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            else
            {   
                $path  = $this->upload->data()['full_path'];
                $image = $this->upload->data()['file_name'];
                // returns the upload dir
                echo json_encode($path);
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        echo json_encode('exists');
    }
}
```

ajax request

```
            var file_data = $('#picture').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();   
            form_data.append('image', file_data);
            form_data.append('firstname', about[0]);
            form_data.append('middlename', about[1]);
            form_data.append('lastname', about[2]);
            form_data.append('email', about[3]);
            form_data.append('number', about[4]);
            form_data.append('username', account[0]);
            form_data.append('password', account[1]);
            form_data.append('rfid', account[2]);
            form_data.append('type', account[3]);
            form_data.append('status', account[4]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: baseurl+"/admin/getImage",
                data: form_data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response){
                        console.log(response)
                        alert('has response')
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('nothing')
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any database saving happening so I can't advise you further than to say that the slashes you are seeing are a result of `json_encode` and are entirely *normal* given the usage of this function. Presumably you are encoding for some jquery/ajax implementation in which case when you parse the result as `JSON` the extra slashes will no longer be there.

I am also not entirely sure, even with a jquery/ajax implementation why you are using `json_encode` as you aren't echoing and object or an array but rather just a string. For example, if an error occurs you have no flag to alert jquery that an error occurred. Typically people do things like `echo json_encode(['status'=>'error', 'data'=>$somedata]);`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated the problem and included the ajax request in it .. TIA

Comment: about the json_encode,  echo wont return anything from the backend .. but when I use json_encode it returns the value

Comment: if you get your json encoded output you will also get a regular echo. there is no mechanic in php or ci to prevent that from happening. you might want to address your testing procedures as they sound incorrrect. i would suggest following `echo json_encode(['status'=>'error', 'data'=>$somedata]); exit;` pattern i mentioned. adding `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax request. and then getting the result via `response.status` and `response.data`. if you have problems use devtools to debug.